# Cakephp: can Model->find('all') return results without model name

Tags: php, cakephp

Using Model->find('all') returns an array with the following structure:

```
array(
  0 => array('Model1' => array(/* Model1 fields*/), 'Model2' => array(/* Model2 fields*/), ...),
  1 => array('Model1' => array(/* Model1 fields*/), 'Model2' => array(/* Model2 fields*/), ...),
  ...)
```

When a single Model is queried (i.e. Recursive = -1), is it possible to have the results returned as an array with the following structure:

```
array(0 => /* Model1 fields*/, 1 => /* Model1 fields*/, etc...)
```

I thought I read this somewhere a while back but cannot figure out how to do this or if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also modify that model's aftersave method so that it returns $data['Modelname'] after it performs the query... In essence, it'd basically be an array shift and you would only have $arrayname['fieldname'] rather than $arrayname['Model']['fieldname'].  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to achieve my desired functionality by defining the afterFind method and flattening the results there.  
foreach($results as $index => $values) { 
  $results[$index] = $values['ModelName']; 
}

Answer (score 2):

What about this ? works in php 5.4+

```
$result = array_map( function ($elem) {
        return $elem['YourModelName'] ;
    } ,$this->Tagcloud-> find('all')
);
```

For older php versions you need to iterate after fetching the results

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are thinking about related models that might get returned this way? AFAIK Cake query results are pretty standardized, and that's a good thing.

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'Model' => array(
            'id',
            'field1',
            ...
         ),
        'belongsTo/hasOneModel' => array(
            'id',
            'field1',
            ...
         )
        'habtm/hasManyModel' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id',
                'field1',
                ...
            ),
            1 => array(
                ...
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Model' => array(
            ...
        ),
        ...
    )
)
```

As you can see, the related HABTM or hasMany models are returned in a "flat" array, but the primary model should always contain the model name.