# CakePHP find not returning correctly - missing model name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

After performing a find on a model I would expect the result to be of the format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ModelName] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 83
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )    
        )
)
```

However, what I appear to be getting is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 83
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )

        )
)
```

Note the missing model name.

I've only been getting this problem since migrating across to what appears to be a very poorly configured VPS that I now have full control over.

My problem is, I can't think of anything that would cause this problem. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out to be very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408663/cakephp-can-model-findall-return-results-without-model-name).

Again the problem was with an outdated pdo_mysql version.

This can be checked by running

`strings -f pdo_mysql.so | grep ': table'`

If there are no results then pdo_mysql is out of date most likely due to an installation such as

```
pecl install pdo_mysql
```

My fix was an easy one

```
yum install php53-mysql
```

I hope that this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, this happens occasionaly to more people